# What privileges does the SQL Azure Migration Wizard need to copy a SQL Azure database?

Tags: backup, security, azure-sql-database

Currently have 2 users in our SQL Azure subscription. One is the god login created when setting up the server, other is very limited account for our www app (has db_datareader and db_datawriter).

The www user does not have enough privileges to use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard. Connecting to server shows the db as grayed out / disabled.

I want to create a 3rd user with just enough privileges to use the mw for copy / backup. What roles / privileges does this user need? Does anyone have some prepared sql scripts?

Answer (score 1):

From 
[Copying Databases in SQL Azure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff951624.aspx)

Permissions

In order to copy a database in SQL Azure, your login requires the following permissions:

On both servers: The login must have the same login name and password on both SQL Azure servers.

On the destination server: The login must be a member of the server-level dbmanager role. Note: the server-level principal of your SQL Azure server is not a member of the dbmanager role, but automatically has the same permissions. For more information about managing logins in SQL Azure, see Managing Databases and Logins in SQL Azure.

On the source server: The login must be the DBO of the source database. Only the login that created the source database, the DBO, can copy that database to another database on the same server or on a different server.